# how to make responsive to wp-featured-content-slider

Tags: slider, wordpress

I need help. I want only WP Featured Content Slider responsive. I have try but fail.

I have also try below link as according but fail to work.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/showing-slider-featured-title-and-content-on-responsive-screen-sizes

plugin link: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-featured-content-slider/

```
/* Tablet Layout: 768px. */

/* Mobile Layout: 320px. */

/* Wide Mobile Layout: 480px. */
```

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to a tablet size /* Tablet Layout: 768px. */
you better hide it with css "display : none;" , it's better than having it not responding to your screen size , i had the same problem as you do